# Are static extension methods on User object safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, static, extension-methods

We have created custom extension methods on the ASP.NET MVC's `User` object, such as this:

```
public static bool IsInAnyRole(this IPrincipal principal, params Role[] roles)
{
    return roles.Select(x => x.ToString()).Any(principal.IsInRole);
}
```

In our controller/Razor views, we can simply say this:

```
if (User.IsInAnyRole(Role.SystemAdmin, Role.Management))
{
     // Do something...
}
```

Various posts on SO indicate that static members aren't thread safe, and they're created once for the whole app. We're worried that the same `IPrincipal` will be used by all users, but we think that can't happen because it's a parameter to the extension method. The only thing that remains constant across all users is the internal functionality of the method.

Are we correct in our understanding? Thanks.

**Update:** "Safe" means the static methods on `IPrincipal` do not share same `User` or `Role[]` objects. We think they won't but wanted to check.

Comment: define "safe"? that's a hugely important distinction; static *fields* are inherently unsafe (if the fields are directly or indirectly mutable); beyond that... impossible to answer; there's nothing unsafe about the method *you've shown*, but that is **specific to the code shown**

Comment: side note: personally I'd be equally interested in the *performance*; that method allocates quite a lot for what it does... whether that *matters* depends a lot on how high throughput it is

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks. Safe == "static methods on `IPrincipal` not sharing anything beyond the internal functionality". Thread-safety is also a concern but not as critical here.

Comment: You have a static method, you don't have a static member. You also do read, no write. It should be all fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up thread safety with the ability to share a variable across instances of objects. An instance variable can be non-thread safe as well and not being thread-safe only means that a variable's value cannot be guaranteed across threads.

As I understand it, what you are looking for is the latter of the two cases of being 'safe': can the method for example return the roles of another user object. Answer is: no, unless that extension method pulls from a static (shared) variable. In your example, it pulls its value from the instance of the class that it's extending, which means that it will not get the value of another instance.

Another approach is this: the extension method isn't determining state of the object, the property (in this case `IsInRole`) is. As that property is invoked over an instance member, you do not have to worry about returning the wrong value here.

"Are we correct in our understanding?": Yes. Actually you already gave the correct answer in your post, only in other words.